# Can PropTypes be used outside React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-proptypes

So I need a type checking package like Proptypes which works on Nodejs.
 I've read their docs and noticed that they had mentioned about using proptypes outside React with checkPropTypes, but one of   checkPropTypes parameters is a Component, which relate to React
Can I use Proptypes in nodejs? If not, can someone recommends a package that has cool things like shape,arrayOf in proptypes. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using typescript? If not maybe create checks utilizing typeof for primitives and instanceof/constructor for non-primitves? Hopefully this will help.

Comment: If you're wanting type safety, TypeScript is king.

Comment: typescript won't do static type check. you may need flow: https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/